# How do I install the "Git Extensions" application in windows 10? I am getting an error installing "Git Extensions"

Tags: git, installation, windows-10, git-extensions

[image]

I am getting the above error on installing the "Git Extensions" application in my windows 10 machine. It starts installation but in between it roll back and finally shows the above error. Any helps appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the last version of the GitExtensions setup for some peoples (See https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/7120 ).

The issue is mostly fixed and a new release will be done (soon?).

edit: (pre) release done! https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/releases/tag/v3.2.1

You could:

- download a previous version (and you will prompted to update when the new release will be done)
- use the fixed setup that was unofficially released for a matter of test (See https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/7120#issuecomment-530316579 )
- Wait for the official 3.2.1 release (but I can't say when it will be released --a matter of days-- because this bug show some other little things that should be ironed out)